Excel custom function in VB
Intention
I would like to create a custom function in excel with VB that concatenates two cells together, separated by a space.
My Attempt (failed)
Function FULLNAME(first, last)

    FULLNAME = Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(first, " ", last)

End Function

or
Function FULLNAME(first,last)
   
   COMBO = first &" "& last
   FULLNAME = Application.Evaluate(COMBO)

End Function

I then select cell D2 and type in =fullname(B2,C2)



Comment
A
B
C
D





1
First Name
Last Name
Result


What I want
2
John
Doe
John Doe


What I get with my attempts
3
John
Doe
=fullname(B2,C2)




Question:
What am I doing wrong, and how can I achieve the result I am intending?

An easier approach with the LAMBDA function is to define a name FULLNAME on your sheet with =LAMBDA(first,last,first&" "&last) as the reference. Then you just use it like a normal function on your sheet - =FULLNAME(A1, B1).

You could also use the built-in =TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:B1) formula.

Or, you know, =A1&" "&B1.

Both the Concat and TextJoin functions in Excel are effective for your question. Why consider developing a custom user-defined function (UDF) when Excel's built-in functions are already suitable?

FULLNAME = first & " " & last. The function using Evaluate does not make too much sense, on my taste...

I just tried your first attempt and it is working fine. As far as your second attempt: why are you evaluating that COMBO? You can just say FULLNAME = COMBO, that will work too.

Summary of what has been written and some own thoughts:
a) The fact that the Cell shows =fullname(B2,C2) instead of the result of the function is most likely caused by the fact that the cell is formatted as Text. In that case Excel will not interpret what is entered as formula (or number, or date) but keep it exactly as it is.
This is true for all kind of formulas, not only for UDFs. Change the format of the cells in column G to anything else (General, for example). Nothing will happen - you need to tell Excel that you have new content for that cell.
Click on the cell containing the formula, click on the formula bar and press enter - Excel will think you entered new content and reinterpret the string. As it starts with an =, now Excel will know it's a formula.
b) There are many ways to concatenate strings in Excel (not VBA). I'm a big fan of writing a small VBA function when a formula gets too complicated, but VBA functions have the big drawback that you need to have VBA enabled, and in professional environments that's not always the case (and not in the hand of the users to change that).
In Excel, there are (at least) 3 ways to concatenate cells B2 and C2
=B2&" "&C2
=CONCAT(B2;" ";C2)
=TEXTJOIN(" ";TRUE;B2:C2)

c) If you want to use VBA to create a function, you should use VBA commands. The string concatenation operator in VBA is &.
Function fullName(first, last)
    fullName = first & " " & last
End Function

The &-operator is pure VBA and has nothing to do with Excel. The same function would work in any other VBA environment (Word, AutoCAD, Powerpoint, Corel, Solidworks...).
Your attempts using Excel functions from VBA will work. Your first version is correct, the second will fail because you are missing quotes - for a corrected version see MGonets answer.
However, this attempts have several drawbacks:
o It limits the usage of the code to Excel
o It makes the code complicated and slow. What happens: (1) Excel asks VBA "Please execute the function fullname for the input John and Doe". (2) VBA asks Excel: "Please concatenate the strings John and Doe for me." (3) Excel returns that concatenation to VBA. (4) VBA returns that result to Excel.
Use WorksheetFunction only when needed - when there is a build-in function in Excel that your code needs (VLookup is a common example). Especially bad is to use Evaluate because in that case you force Excel first to parse the content of the argument.

The first function is correct, the second should read:
Function FULLNAME1(first, last)
   Dim COMBO As String
   COMBO = first & " " & last
   FULLNAME1 = Application.Evaluate("""" & COMBO & """")
End Function

If you don't get the result your cells are probably formatted as text. Should be General format.

The second function shouldn't read that, it shouldn't exist in the first place. Application.Evaluate("""John Doe""") does not really make sense.

Did you try? The variable COMBO is defined in VBA, not in the workbook.

The function shouldn't exist because it makes absolute no sense to run Evaluate against a constant string. You simply write FULLNAME1 = COMBO (argh, those uppercase names hurt my eyes)
